# Python printing comma when i try to print string and variables

Tags: python

I am new to python and I was trying to print strings with variables however I am not getting the desired output.
I get the correct output on online editior.

```
a = 300
a
b = "Shyam"
b
print('a --', a)  
print("b -->", b)
```

The output in my screen is given below

[image]

Comment: What is the desired result? There should be no commas as it is

Comment: You're running Python 2 instead of Python 3.